# Word 365 Headings that take up multiple Lines

Tags: microsoft-word

I am attempting to make

[image: Text]

I would like the larger font to be the heading, is it possible to make a heading that would textwrap lines and float on the left side?  As shown in the photo you can see that the heading would take up 2 lines in the normal text and the text warps around it.  Can you do this in Word?

Comment: I see a big roman number, but not title. Which one is the heading here?

Comment: You don't need to see a title to understand that what is inferred is the III is a heading.  Perhaps Q&A isn't something you should involve yourself in.

Comment: The III appears to be a DropCap. That is essentially text in a Frame, which is paragraph formatting.

Comment: @Case no need to get worked up. We are here to help and we are doing this for free. Reddy asked a valid questions since it makes quite a large difference whether you only want a few characters to take up multiple lines or really full words / headings. As Charles suggested, look into DropCaps. If you want a heading style that automatically formats that way, simply create a DropCap, then select the text in it, right-click on the heading style and update the heading style to match selection.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Charles, what you are showing in your image is a DropCap (tab: Insert, section: Text). Now, if you want your heading style to automatically convert the heading text into a DropCap:

1. Create a DropCap in your document
2. Select the text within the DropCap
3. Right-click the heading style and "Update Heading to Match Selection"